# Find AD Groups Of all Users in the list

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

My PowerShell code is not working :(

Also, how can I export the results to a CSV file please ?

I have a list of users (samnames), I am trying to export their AD Groups into a CSV file.

Below is my attempt:

```
$list = ForEach ($list in $(Get-Content users.txt))
$list | `
    %{  
        $user = $_; 
        get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | `
        select -expand memberof | `
        %{new-object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}} `
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your script like you are missing a statement block in your first foreach loop. Also you can simplify it a lot like:

```
Get-Content users.txt | ForEach-Object {
        $user = $_; 
        get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | 
            select -expand memberof | 
            ForEach-Object {
                New-Object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}
            }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'your_file_path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I.e my export looks like. User - CN#=Group,OU=Local server,OU=DH, etc. I only want to see the group name. can you please help ? Thanks for your help Martin

Comment: I am trying a different approach, which is also not working :(

Comment: I only want to see group names. Instead i am getting (CN#=Group,OU=Local server,OU=DH). Can you help please ? Thanks

Comment: Also the group name sorted by A-Z for each user please Can you help ? Many thanks